# how to subset everything after first row containing a numeric value

Tags: r, subset

Subsetting question.  I would prefer to use built in R functions but doesn't have to be.  I believe solution is simple, but Im new to R.

Here is example data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"),
              C1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
              C2 = c(NA, NA, 35, 20, NA, 50),
              C3=1:6)
```

Output looks like this:

```
  year C1 C2 C3
1 2001  a NA  1
2 2002  b NA  2
3 2003  c 35  3
4 2004  d 20  4
5 2005  e NA  5
6 2006  f 50  6
```

I want to select all columns starting at the first row with a numeric value (ie, >0) in column C2, so that my output would look like this:

```
  year C1 C2 C3
1 2003  c 35  3
2 2004  d 20  4
3 2005  e NA  5
4 2006  f 50  6
```

Notice the NA in column C2 row 3 is not excluded (which is desired).  I've tried the following, but it excludes NA rows:

```
new_df=subset(df, C2>0)
```

Ive also tried this but doesn't work either:

```
new_df=subset(df, C2>0 | is.na(C2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[which(!is.na(df$C2))[1]:nrow(df),]
```

Output:

```
  year C1 C2 C3
3 2003  c 35  3
4 2004  d 20  4
5 2005  e NA  5
6 2006  f 50  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, you can create a custom function that takes as input the data frame and the column you want to use for the subseting,

```
f1 <- function(df, x){
  i1 <- which(is.na(x))
  v1 <- i1==1
  l2 <- c(v1[1], diff(i1) == 1)
  ifelse(v1, return(df[-which(l2),]), 
         return(df))
}

#apply the function
f1(df, df$C2)
```

which gives,

> ```
>   year C1 C2 C3
> 3 2003  c 35  3
> 4 2004  d 20  4
> 5 2005  e NA  5
> 6 2006  f 50  6
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   slice(which(!is.na(C2)):n())
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#    year     C1    C2    C3
#  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#1   2003      c    35     3
#2   2004      d    20     4
#3   2005      e    NA     5
#4   2006      f    50     6
```

---

Or with `cumsum/filter`

```
df %>%
     filter(cumsum(!is.na(C2))>0)
#  year C1 C2 C3
#1 2003  c 35  3
#2 2004  d 20  4
#3 2005  e NA  5
#4 2006  f 50  6
```

These methods can also be done with `base R`

```
df[cumsum(!is.na(df$C2)) > 0,]
```